# AJAX form only works once in IE9

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I'm writing a simple script that submits the registration form to my site via ajax. It works perfectly in modern browsers. In IE9 the form only submits properly once. Then if I try to submit the same form again, the second time the form never returns and the loader gif remains permanently. Any idea why this is happening?

EDIT: I should have pointed out that I'm using this [jquery form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#faq) to submit the form. Secondly, when I inspect the source after submitting the form, the correct markup is there. I can manually add opacity styles to reveal the form, so I think this suggests the problem is connected to IE9 and the jquery fade functions.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
    return (s)
      ? this.before(s).remove()
      : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $("form input").removeAttr('tabindex');

        ajaxregister = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).fadeTo(500, 0);
            $(this).siblings("#loading").fadeIn();
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                //url:'http://streetofwalls.dev/wp-login.php?action=register'
                success: function( data ) {
                    //console.log(data);

                    var $message = $(data).find('.message').outerHTML();
                    var $error = $(data).find('#login_error').outerHTML();
                    var $form = $(data).find('#registerform').outerHTML();
                    console.log( 'success' );

                    $(e.target).html( ( ($error) ? $error : $message ) + $form ).fadeTo(500,1);
                    $(e.target).siblings("#loading").fadeOut();

                }
            });
        }

        $(".widget_reg_widg #registerform").submit( ajaxregister );
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use console.log in IE browsers, it makes javascript stop executing.

Comment: I removed it. Same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by replacing the `e.target` with jquery selectors. See the last few lines of the success: function() {...

```
                success: function( data ) {

                    var $message = $(data).find('.message').outerHTML();
                    var $error = $(data).find('#login_error').outerHTML();
                    var $form = $(data).find('#registerform').outerHTML();

                    var target_id = $(e.target).attr("id");
                    $("#"+target_id).html( ( ($error) ? $error : $message ) + $form ).animate({opacity:1}, 500);
                    $("#"+target_id).css('display', 'block');

                    $("#"+target_id).siblings("#loading").css('display', 'none');

                }
```

Not sure why that worked. It must have something to do with the way IE9 references the event.

Answer (score 1):

In some IE browsers, you must redifine the event variable:

```
ajaxregister = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking in the IE status bar if anounces any error? Have you tried pressing F12 to see any aditional information?

Comment: I'm watching the console and I don't get any errors. Can you elaborate on the F12 info? I'm running IE in VMWare so some of the shortcuts don't work (F12 hides my desktop on OSX).

Comment: Well, F12 only opens the console. Executing in other browsers doesn't give you any errors, also?

Comment: No errors in Chrome's console. Also the form works repeatedly in all other browsers (presumably because there inn't an error).

Answer (score 0):

use `cache:false` in your jquery code.

**Example :**

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({
    cache : false,
    //existing code
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't do it. It still hangs after the second submit.

Comment: I wonder, did you notice that the I'm using the jquery ajax form plugin? Or is the `cache` option specific to $.ajax()?

Comment: @Emerson, this jquery ajax form plugin supports all the options of $.ajax.